# Domain app being rejected for not implementing SSO

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We are an existing web application where schools are subscriptions and students under that school can use our web app. They currently have logins with projects under the logins.

Since students keep forgetting logins, schools want to start migrating to Google Apps marketplace app approach where all students have to do is click on universal navigation icon.

But since the students could already have an account with us, the first time they login from universal icon, they are provided with a screen to map any existing account or create a new one. Once that is done, next time the student comes in, they login and enter the app right away. No intermediate steps.

With that background, our marketplace app is being rejected with the reason, we do not implement SSO.

Can somebody help me understand how are we not implementing SSO?

Comment: Have you followed the steps mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en) in order to set up Single Sign-on for your Google Apps account?

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with mismatch credentials in the marketplace app and PHP code.

Used the same API keys in both places fixed it.